# Do select elements have a standard value property?

Tags: javascript, dom, selectedvalue

This is a simple question but I cannot find any reference so here it goes.

Assume I have a select element:

```
<select id="sel">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

Now I want to get its selected option's `value`. Most often I see this kind of snippet being used:

```
var sel = document.getElementById('sel');
console.log( sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value ); //1
```

Which works great. However, I've found out that `select` elements also have a value property:

```
console.log( sel.value ); //1
```

See [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/h9Sba/) with both examples.

The second form is not only much simpler, it also works all the way back to IE6 (yes, I did actually test on that, here's the [IE6 friendly version](http://jsfiddle.net/h9Sba/1/show)).

Is there a reason why the first approach is so much more widely accepted? Is there some incompatibility or corner-case issue with the second approach?

ps. My "most used approach" thesis was based mostly on personal experience, but as for reference, the two most upvoted answers in [Get selected value in dropdown list using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/how-to-get-the-selected-value-of-dropdownlist-using-javascript) uses the first approach.

Comment: What happens when multiple values are selected?

Comment: Relevant MDN page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLSelectElement

Comment: @PaulS. I see. The `value` returns the first selected option's value. You could use that in an answer.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté, it is not a good idea to ask for issues with corner-cases when you ignore corner cases.

Comment: @zzzzBov Ok my bad, let's take multiple values in account then.

Comment: @PaulS. I was looking at the `HTMLInputElement` but failed to find the `HTMLSelectElement`. That was pretty much which I was looking for.

Comment: @zzzzBov Even with the `multiple` property, both have the same output apparently http://jsfiddle.net/h9Sba/2/

Comment: @FabrícioMatté *The `value` returns the first selected option's value*. That basically doesn't give any reason, since *`selectedIndex` is the index of the first selected `<option>` element*.

Comment: @VisioN What doesn't give reason? My thesis that `selectedIndex` is more used? From what I understand now after reading the references, both are equivalent.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté I'm just referring to your [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15661298/do-select-elements-have-a-standard-value-property#comment22227149_15661298).

Comment: @VisioN I meant that a `select`'s `value` property returns its first selected `option`'s `value`.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté In fact my first question was: *is it really so that approach with `selectedIndex` is more used?* Could you provide examples of that?

Comment: @VisioN Mostly personal experience, but I'll provide links shortly.

Comment: @VisioN edited question to add reference.

Comment: As for browser compatibility, AFAIR there was an issue in older IE (6, I think), that this would only work if the `option` elements actually had a `value` attribute. (Which is not required – the standard defines that the value of an option with no value _attribute_ is the text content of the option.)

Comment: @FabrícioMatté [Paolo's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1085810/1249581) was mostly referring to picking up the `text` of selected option, but not to its value.

Comment: @CBroe I don't have IE6 to test, but if that's true then it seems it would make a reasonable answer.

Comment: @VisioN The question itself was asking for a `value`. Of course, I understand he may have used that approach so both value and `text` is obtained in a similar manner.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks! Though I just tested and in that case both would fail (both return an empty string). `:(`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [**MDN page**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLSelectElement) tells us

> `options` *nsIDOMHTMLOptionsCollection*   The set of  elements contained by this element. Read only.
>
> `selectedIndex`   *long*  The index of the first selected  element.
>
> `value`   *DOMString* The value of this form control, that is, of the first selected option.

However it also says

> `selectedOptions` **Unimplemented (see bug 596681)**  *HTMLCollection*    The set of options that are selected. HTML5

Therefore, if you want to have a multi-select but general compatibility, you'll have to loop over `options`, but if you have a single-select, `sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value` and `sel.value` are equivalent, but the prior is "more similar" to the form a loop for a multi-select would take.

Comment: Thanks, seeing the definition of the `select`'s `value` property in MDN relieves me as it is a standard property and not one of those introduced in HTML5. Guess I was just unaware of it until not long ago.

Answer (score 1):

The first option is widely accepted only because its more well known. The 2nd option is perfectly fine.

Have you verified that it works on Navigator 4?

Comment: I only support old IE as it is widely used in some parts of the world, unfortunately. For other major browsers besides IE, I only test with the latest versions. Firefox 2 usage should be close to none even when compared to IE6 usage.