# Getting option value from select control: .value vs .options[selectedIndex].value?

Tags: javascript, html, html-select

I've seen the question "How does one determine selected option value in a HTML SELECT control" asked more times than I care to count - [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/how-to-get-the-selected-value-of-dropdownlist-using-javascript) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11828485/get-the-option-value-in-select-in-javascript) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11828125/how-to-get-the-value-of-a-selected-text-in-javascript) for instance.

These questions all have something in common, they usually suggest one of the following methods:

```
//Method 1
document.getElementById("SelectControlsID").value;
```

OR

```
//Method 2
document.getElementById("SelectControlsID").options[document.getElementById("SelectControlsID").selectedIndex].value;
```

**Question 1:** I presume Method 2 is a relic from the past needed for some archaic browser that doesn't support calling `.value` directly? If so, which browsers still require the `options[]` method? Is this an ECMAScript spec issue?

**Question 2:** When writing new code, is it safe to just use Method 1 or is Method 2 still advisable (JQuery aside)?

Comment: It seems that this question may already be answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15661298/do-select-elements-have-a-standard-value-property

Comment: @DavidThomas Well spotted! That question seems to suggest that .value is fine on IE6+ and that IE6 .value didn't work if there was no value tag on the option tag - interesting!

Comment: To my mind, what it suggests is that .value (method 1) is fine if your select doesn't allow for multiple selections. If it does, use .options (method 2), but method 2 will work in both cases.